# Facebook Messenger keeps on playing sound in notification

Tags: notifications, audio, facebook-messenger, samsung-galaxy-s-9, silent-mode

I'm using facebook Messenger on a Samsung Galaxy S9. Since a few months now, Messenger keeps on playing a notification sound when receiving chat messages even when I change the sound to Silent.

Let's be precise :

- When going in Messenger parameters and choosing a notification sound, there is no "silent" sound (and I'm pretty sure it existed before)
- When going into "Manage notification" from the app which leads to the notification management of the OS, I can chose "silent" as a sound but after a while (1/2 hours or so, sometimes less), messenger changes it back automatically to its default sound.

That's driving me crazy. I want to keep notification as I used to : vibration, preview but no sound.

I tried to delete and reinstall the app, nothing has changed. I even left a message in the Play store.

Any idea ? Thanks

Comment: Have you found a way to make the change permanently. I have the same problem here with my Moto G4 and my new Galaxy A50. I want to keep the vibration so I have to select "Silent" for the sound but it always come back to the messenger sound.

Comment: Unfortunately I gave up. I chose silent. At least it doesn't ring. But I can't have the vibration either